# Bullet destroy 2 game object intent one unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my bullet Collides with a Ball if there is 2 Balls at near or at the same position, all object get destroyed at same time. I set in my script when bullet collide with other then player it will be destroy.

I was trying to check every ball type with else if

```
 if(other.gameObject.tag == "yerrow")
    { 
        if (ballType >= 0 && ballType < 4)
        {

            clone1 = (GameObject)Instantiate(_ball, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            clone1.gameObject.GetComponent<Balloon_Behave>().ballMove = -4;
            clone1.gameObject.GetComponent<Balloon_Behave>().transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - Random.Range(0, 0.5f), transform.position.y - Random.Range(0,1));

            clone2 = Instantiate(_ball, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else if (ballType == 4)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        Debug.Log("Yerrow COLl");
    }
```

Yerrow Script Destroy himself

```
  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
      {  
         if (other.gameObject.tag != "Player")
          {
             Destroy(this.gameObject);
             player.CanFire = true;
          }
      }
```

EDIT NOTE : Every ball collides with bulled is destroy intent one. I want to destroy one object by one bullet

Comment: It's probably because your bullet is too fast and before it detect the first collision it register another. What you could do is disable the collider when it collided with something, it should prevent firing twice

Comment: yerrow, bullet, ball, player, 4 types or just 2?

Comment: I just try to decrease speed too slow and try it. Result is same.

Comment: @shingo yerrow is tag of bullet, ball is target object its short by player

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set bool to check ball bullet hit the ball or not and make it false if bullet collides with ball.

```
 public Player _player

 void start(){
 _powerUP = GameObject.Find("player").GetComponent<Player>();
 }

 if(other.gameObject.tag == "yerrow" && _player.canBe == true)
    {
        _player.canBe = false; // False just after hit
        if (ballType >= 0 && ballType < 4)
        {
            clone1 = (GameObject) Instantiate(_ball, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            clone1.gameObject.GetComponent<Balloon_Behave>().ballMove = -4;
            clone1.gameObject.GetComponent<Balloon_Behave>().transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - Random.Range(0, 1f), transform.position.y - Random.Range(0,1));
             Instantiate(_ball, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else if(ballType == 4)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }  
    }
```

Don't true this value in Bullet On trigger, make it true when call Instantiate Clone, then it should work find.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these 2 functions, and use active flag to check the bullet status.

```
//Check if the bullet is active, then destroy the ball.
if(other.gameObject.tag == "yerrow" && other.gameObject.activeSelf)
{ 
    if (ballType >= 0 && ballType < 4)
    {
        ...
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    else if (ballType == 4)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    //Destroy and deactive the bullet here
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed still target more then one object

Answer (score 0):

On the ball, inside `OnCollisionEnter2D`

```
if(collision.collider.tag=="BulletTag")
{
     Destroy(collision.collider.gameObject);
     Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Apply this onto the *ball* only.